# Why is the number of words in a text file incorrect in my C program?

Tags: c, file, text-files, file-handling

I'm trying to count the number of words in a file. I wrote the code below:

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
{
    if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0')
    {
        no_of_words = no_of_words + 1;
    }
}
```

For a text file with the following contents it's printing the number of words as `8` whereas I'm expecting `6`.

```
Hi, we are here.

huio klhi
```

Comment: To begin with, do you remember that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**? Which is very important for that comparison agains the `int` value `EOF`. Secondly, in a plain text file there shouldn't really be any null-terminator characters.

Comment: There are 4 `' '`s, ` 3 `'\n'`s, and 1 `'\0'`. That is 8 in total.

Comment: And, what are you ***really*** counting? Please explain it in great detail to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Actually, there probably isn't a `'\0'` in the file, but perhaps there is another one of those characters in there, or perhaps you initialized `number_of_words` to 1. The point is, you need to count non-empty sequences of the complement of those characters.

Comment: `how   many      words         are          in           this        sentence?`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: Seems like `isspace(int ch)` would come in handy here - includes your set (sans `'\0'`) and a few others (e.g. `'\r'`).  (ctype.h).

Comment: @Computable but that won't help for the OP's problem though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are counting `no_of_words` up also when `ch` is a newline (`\n`), the two extra line breaks you have in your text file are also counted as new words.

What you can do instead is have another variable that keeps track of whether you are currently within a word. Each time a word starts, count it up; but don't count while you are within white-space:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int ch;
    bool in_word = false;
    int no_of_words = 0;
    FILE *fptr = fopen("example.txt", "r");

    while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\t')
        {
            in_word = false;
        } else
        if (!in_word)
        {
            in_word = true;
            no_of_words = no_of_words + 1;
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    printf("words: %d\n", no_of_words);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, there is no need to check `ch` for `\0` (0) because the last value you will receive from `fgetc` will be `EOF` (usually defined as -1).  Because `ch` can receive more than 256 different values, it must be defined with type `int`.

Comment: Assuming that `ch` is of type `int`, you can write `if ( isspace( ch ) )` instead of `if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\t')`. Note that this requires `#include <ctype.h>`.